# How to make a collapsable sidebar with tabpanel in ExtJs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a vertical tabpanel (sidebar like). Every tab has an icon and a title.
I want to add a menu button and make this panel collapsable. When it's collapsed, you only see the icon (like in this example: examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard).

Main.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype:  'app-main',
    id:     'app-main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.plugin.Viewport',
        'Ext.window.MessageBox',
         ...
    ],

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel:  'main',

    ui: 'navigation',

    header: {
        flex:   1,
        height: 30,
        cls:    'main-header',
        layout: {
            type:  'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        }
    },

    // sidebar settings
    tabRotation: 0,
    tabPosition: 'left',
    tabBar:      {
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        }
    },

    //activeTab: 1,
    items: [
        {
        title:         "tab1",
        xtype:         'tab1x',
        iconCls:       'x-fa fa-file sidebar-tab-icon',
        index:         1
    }
    ...
    ]
});
```

[image]

Comment: I dont think that its tabpanel in example, atleast there is no easy way to add menu to it and make it collapsible like you want. I think you can check example code - http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/admin-dashboard/classic/app.js (its obfuscated, but still readable).

Comment: @SergeyNovikov yes, i know it's not a tabpanel. I have the source of this example - https://github.com/bjornharrtell/extjs/tree/master/templates/admin-dashboard

But i have to change too much stuff to make it work. I was wondering if it was possible to adjust my code and create the same effect with my tabpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it partially in js and part in css. Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1paa&view/editor).